# Node.js recursive function with super agent

Tags: node.js, recursion

I'm developing a simple function that, making use of [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) module, query an API service to retrieve information splitted in several pages.

As soon as I finish each call I have to push the information into an array and then as I retrieved the last page, start working on this array.

Using a normal way for sure I'll have problem due to async-ness, so I need something like callback or event emitter to get rid of this.

Atm I used this code, but this doesn't work:

```
function getPage(page){
  pages = new Array()
  superagent.get('http://localhost/api.json')
  .end(function(r){
   if(r[r.length-1] == 'value')
    getPage(page++)
   else
    pages.push(r);
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at async.js, it's a really useful library that can help you with this.